# What is Optional({}) at Alamofire mean when i create output of JSON

Tags: swift, alamofire

When I create output of JSON using Alamofire, I saw this in my console
What does `Optional({})` mean?

```
Optional({
    0 =     (
        All,
        ""
    );
    C2001 =     (
        "ARAI Bay Side"
    );
    C2002 =     (
        "ARAI Fukuoka"
    );
})
```

I am newbie to `swift` and this, so any ideas?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Alamofire gives you is an optional variable, because it can't predict in advance whether the request will succeed and have output or fail and have none.

Similarly, it also gives you an `error?` variable (note the `?`, which means it's also an optional) that will be `nil` if the request succeeded or will be something (most likely an `NSError`) if an error occurred.

You can check with `if yourVariable != nil` to see whether the optional variable is set (contains something), in which case you'll be able to unwrap it with `yourVariable!`.

You can also use the following :

```
if let yourUnwrappedVariable = yourVariable!
```

to unwrap the variable into a new (non-optional) `yourUnwrappedVariable` variable and execute the code in that `if` block if the variable was set (contained something, wasn't `nil`), this time without needing to unwrap the variable again like the previous example (here you already have the `yourUnwrappedVariable` variable and can use it right away in that if block).

Finally, if you're sure the variable will always be set, you can unwrap it by passing it followed by a `!` sign to whatever method call you want like so :

```
myMethod(initWithData: yourVariable!, anotherArgument: anotherValue)
```

If the variable ever happens to not contain anything, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.it was such a great answer to understand for a newbie

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the output from global functions like `print()` or `println()`, which enclose optional descriptions inside `Optional( )`, unless the value of the optional is nil, in which case just `nil` is printed.

If you have this:

```
var foo: Int?
foo = 7
println(foo)
```

The output is `Optional(7)`

whereas

```
println(foo!)
```

just prints `7`